# How can I get the next 2 stop times for each bus that passes a stop (GTFS data)?

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

My goal is simple. In my app, the user would press on a stop and it would open a screen displaying each route (bus) that is going by that stop and display the next 2 stop times for each route at that stop. Example of what I want to display when user presses stop with stop id of 1571:

*Buses traveling by stop 569*

**Route 2**
23 minutes (7:23 AM)
43 minutes (7:43 AM)

**Route 37**
15 minutes (7:15 AM)
45 minutes (7:45 AM)

Example data returned (what I want):
**st.departure_time, rte.route_long_name, tr.trip_headsign**
07:23:00, Route 2, Downtown
07:43:00, Route 2, Downtown
07:15:00, Route 37, Downtown
07:45:00, Route 37, Downtown

It should be noted that the stop code is 569 and the stop id is 1571. As per [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/) documentation, a user would usually search the stop code (569) but internally the stop id (1571) is what is searched. These come from the stops.txt file in a GTFS package.

The example is displaying 2 routes (2 and 37) but there could be more routes, there could be only 1 route, or there could be no routes at all passing this stop in the near future (I want to ignore times that are more than 24 hours away).

Disclaimer: I am not so good with SQL. I was able to create a query that appears to retrieve relevant data, however, it returns way more data than just the next 2 stop times for each route. I am parsing it in my app to get the desired results but I feel like it would be a lot easier to just improve my query.

```
SELECT stop_times.departure_time, routes.route_long_name, trips.trip_headsign, calendar.monday, calendar.tuesday, calendar.wednesday, calendar.thursday, calendar.friday, calendar.saturday, calendar.sunday
FROM stop_times, trips, routes, calendar
WHERE stop_times.stop_id = '1571' AND stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id AND trips.route_id = routes.route_id AND trips.service_id = calendar.service_id AND 20180801 >= calendar.start_date AND 20180801 <= calendar.end_date
ORDER BY routes.route_short_name, trips.service_id, stop_times.departure_time
```

Here are the relevant tables. I store my data in database exactly as specified in the [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/) documentation.

[stops.txt](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#stopstxt) example rows:
[image]

[routes.txt](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#routestxt) example rows:
[image]

[trips.txt](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#tripstxt) example rows:
[image]

[stop_times.txt](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#stop_timestxt) example rows:
[image]

[calendar.txt](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#calendartxt) example rows:
[image]

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I will work on creating the MCVE now, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the things you could already do is use the standard JOIN notation.

It's more readable, and less prone to causing an accidental cartesian join.

And using short alias names can make a SQL more concise .

```
SET @StopId = '1571';
SET @CalDate = cast('2018-08-01' as date);

SELECT 
 st.departure_time, 
 rte.route_long_name, 
 tr.trip_headsign,
 cal.monday, cal.tuesday, cal.wednesday, cal.thursday, cal.friday, 
 cal.saturday, cal.sunday
FROM stop_times AS st
JOIN trips AS tr ON tr.trip_id = st.trip_id
JOIN routes AS rte ON rte.route_id = tr.route_id
JOIN calendar AS cal ON cal.service_id = tr.service_id
WHERE st.stop_id = @StopId
AND @CalDate between cal.start_date and cal.end_date
ORDER BY rte.route_short_name, tr.service_id, st.departure_time
```

As for that requirement to get the next 2 stops per route?

Here's an example SQL for that.
It includes a check on the weekday. Not sure if that's needed, so that's just to demonstrate.

A SQL Fiddle for it can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19160/13/3)

```
SET @StopId = 1571;
SET @CalDate = cast('2018-08-01' as date);
SET @StartTime = cast('08:00:00' as time);

SELECT departure_time, route_long_name, trip_headsign
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
     st.departure_time,
     tr.service_id,
     rte.route_short_name,
     rte.route_long_name,
     tr.trip_headsign,
     @num := if(@prev_routeid = tr.route_id, @num + 1, 1) as RN,
     @prev_routeid := tr.route_id as route_id
    FROM stop_times AS st
    JOIN trips AS tr ON tr.trip_id = st.trip_id
    JOIN routes AS rte ON rte.route_id = tr.route_id
    JOIN calendar AS cal ON cal.service_id = tr.service_id
    -- LEFT JOIN stops AS s on s.stop_id = st.stop_id
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @num := 0, @type := '') AS vars
    WHERE st.stop_id = @StopId
    AND @CalDate between cal.start_date and cal.end_date
    AND (CASE WEEKDAY(@CalDate)
        WHEN 0 THEN monday 
        WHEN 1 THEN tuesday 
        WHEN 2 THEN wednesday
        WHEN 3 THEN thursday
        WHEN 4 THEN friday
        WHEN 5 THEN saturday
        WHEN 6 THEN sunday
        END) = 1
    AND st.departure_time >= @StartTime
    ORDER BY tr.route_id, st.departure_time
) Q
WHERE RN <= 2
ORDER BY route_short_name, service_id, departure_time;
```

**Side-note:**
*The RN is calculated in an old MySql 7 style, using variables.

In MySql 8 the window function ROW_NUMBER can be used instead.*

Comment: Thank you. That does look much easier to read. Do you know how I would only return the next 2 times for each stop? From what I can tell this answer is the as I have already (but much easier to understand)?

Comment: @user3614030 could you add some expected result based on sample data to your question then? It could avoid a misunderstanding what you mean by 'next 2 stops'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added "example data". I mean the next 2 times each bus would be coming by the stop. For example if it is 07:20:00 (7:20 AM), for route 2 the next bus would come at 07:23:00 and the bus after that would come at 07:43:00. I do not want the stop times before 07:20:00 (for example when the bus came at 07:00:00) and I do not want times after the first 2 buses (even though a 3rd bus for the route is coming at 08:03:00 I want to ignore it since I only want the route's first 2 bus times).

Comment: @user3614030 I mocked up some sample data for it and based a solution on it. See updated answer. It contains a link to a SQL fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful.

Comment: @user3614030 That's good. But I just noticed that it required a small fix. The route_id had to be added to the ORDER BY of the sub-query.  That's to make sure that the logic with the `@prev_routeid` variable is done correctly.